# Hover on div containing other div doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you take a look on [ihavenotv.com](http://ihavenotv.com), when you hover on the divs having the class "episodeTop" the border-bottom changes color (from green to orange). This works as expected.

However, if you switch to a secondary page, [like this one](http://ihavenotv.com/series/origins-the-journey-of-humankind), I am inserting some numbers from jQuery, inside a  and a  (in the lower left part) and the hover doesn't work as expected anymore :(

I have tried various things but couldn't get it to work as on the frontpage.

Comment: Looks like `margin-top: -60px;` on the `episodeNumber` element is **hiding** the `episodeTop` element's `border-bottom`. I just changed `margin-top` to `-51px` and then you can see the bottom border changing.

Comment: Thanks Mr Meeseeks, you are right. Do you happen to know what could I do so that the number doesn't get the border-bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change episodeNumber class position:relative to absolute.